# can no longer Buy fire or explosive arrows in Far Cry 4

Tags: far-cry-4

I just got done doing the Himalayan mission for the CIA guy and after that mission I cannot restock any of my explosive arrows or fire arrows in Far Cry 4 for PS3. What gives?

Comment: Does the game say anything, or are they just not available for purchase?